# PWA The "ENVFILEPATH" variable is not set

Tags: pwa-studio, environment-variable, devops

When I run `docker-compose up -d` in my brand new cloned PWA Studio repo, this is what I got:

```
WARN[0000] The "ENVFILEPATH" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
Failed to load /projects/pwa-studio: read /projects/pwa-studio: is a directory
```

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run docker-compose from the root folder as it came from the PWA Studio repo. You need to set up some stuff before.

That's why the repo comes with the folder **docker**, allowing you to set it up more quickly. You need to run this command below. If you have any issues, run it twice.

```
./docker/run-docker
```

This directory stores certificates for local SSL/TLS, created by running run-docker script, as well as configuration for docker environment setup.

Run the `docker/run-docker` script from the root of the repository to create a container running PWA with a secure https protocol.

This script will:

- copy the .env.docker environment variables to .env to be easily consumable by docker-compose
- add a custom domain, configured in .env.docker
- generate a self-signed ssl/tls certificate and trust the certificate using devcert in the makeHostAndCert.js script
- run docker-compose build to build the container network
- run docker-compose up to start the container running PWA at the custom domain with https

After docker/run-docker is executed from the root of the repository, the default configuration will have the PWA application running at https://pwa-docker.localhost.